# having problems trying to render html content inside template

Tags: javascript, lodash

Having the following lodash template source

```
<script id="resume-template" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td>Curriculum</td>
        <td>
            <%= _.unescape(resume.curriculum) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

And having the following context

```
const context = {
    resume: {
        email: '...',
        firstName: '...',
        lastName: '...',
        curriculum: "&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;some important information goes here&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;unordered list&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;ul&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;item1&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;item2&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;item3&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;item4&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;/ul&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;ordered list&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;ol&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;pet1&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;pet2&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;pet3&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;pet4&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;/ol&amp;gt;\r\n&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Some &amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;text-decoration: line-through;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;text-decoration: underline;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;other&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt; &amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;text-decoration: underline;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;information&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt; &amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;text-decoration: line-through;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;goes&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt; &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;here&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;"
    }
}
```

And the following implementation

```
const app = document.querySelector('#app');
const resume = response; // ajax response
const source = document.querySelector('#resume-template').innerHTML;
const template = _.template(source);

app.innerHTML = template(resume);
```

I need to render the content of the resume.curriculum key as html, in order of accomplish this I first unescape the resume.curriculum content `<%= _.unscape(resume.curriculum) %>`,  but instead of getting the html, I get the html tags and their content as text

As a help, if in template I place the following content `<%= '<p><i>Some content</i></p>' %>` is appropriately rendered as html

I appreciate any help to solve this scenario

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your server-side code you have double-escaped your `curriculum` field.  See this chunk:

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;some important information goes here&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

That should be:

```
&lt;p&gt;some important information goes here&lt;/p&gt;
```

So, fix your server-side code and you'll see your stuff start working.  To verify this, just change this:

```
<td>
  <%= _.unescape(resume.curriculum) %>
</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
  <%= _.unescape(_.unescape(resume.curriculum)) %>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, very good observation, check your suggestion and it is solved with double escape, working on your suggestion now. Thanks again for the time